# What is the purpose of having 'attr' in linker scripts

Tags: gcc, ld, linker-scripts

What is the purpose of having 'attr' in linker scripts. I see that the allowed fields are "ALIRWX". The linker manual   [1]: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_mono/ld.html#SEC16 does not explain what happens if it is not mentioned. Say for e.g., what will happen if I dont mark the section as 'X' and leaving it blank. Same applies for 'Read-Only' sections too.

Answer (score 0):

Memory attibutes are not meant to **enforce** anything, but rather to give `ld` an idea of your target environment. You tell it which memory area is usable for what purpose in order to help it decide on where things have to go.

E.g. if you have hardware that can suppress program execution from a specific memory area (or suppresses that by design, like in a true Harvard architecture), you would leave out the 'X' to tell ld that it cannot expect to execute code from there.

If you omit the (optional) *>region* statement from your `SECTIONS` assignment, `ld` will assign the most appropriate memory region based on your definitions.